# Sort list A2 A4 A1 A3 to A1 A2 A3 A4

Tags: sorting, amazon-dynamodb, ironpython, revit-api

I have a list which contains items like A2 A4 A1 A3 B1 B3 B4 A5 B2. I would like to sort it into a list that looks like A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 and then B1 B2 B3 B4 etc..

I have build a script (ironpython) which could be a step in the right direction but I have the feeling there could be an easier way. My questions are:

- How can I sort the zipped list using the items in the list created in e? I haven't found a way to do this yet. In the current state the script only puts the items beginning with an A together, but not in the numeric order A1, A2, A3 etc...
- Is there another approach to sort the list as described?

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('ProtoGeometry')
from Autodesk.DesignScript.Geometry import *

#The inputs to this node will be stored as a list in the IN variables.
dataEnteringNode = IN
import re
output = []
n = 0
stramienen = IN[0]
gridcurves = IN[1]
var = True
b = []
c = []
e = []
for x in stramienen:
    def hasNumbers(inputString):
        return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString)
    if (hasNumbers(stramienen[n])) == var:
        b.append(stramienen[n])
        c.append(gridcurves[n])
        e.append(re.findall('\d+',stramienen[n]))
        
    n=n+1
d=zip(b,c,e)
# take second element for sort
def takeSecond(elem):
    return elem[0][0]

# sort list with key
d.sort(key=takeSecond)

#Assign your output to the OUT variable.
OUT = d
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*sorted()* is used to sort a list in Python

```
>>> mylist=["B3","A3","A4","B2","A2","B1","A1"]

>>> sorted(mylist)
['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']

>>> for i in sorted(mylist): print(i)
... 
A1
A2
A3
A4
B1
B2
B3
>>>
```

I feel you need to attend few classes in python. Ex:

-Define method (*def myfunction*) outside *for* loop

-Comparison for boolean data is True or False

```
def hasNumbers(inputString):
    return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString)

for x in stramienen:
 if hasNumbers(stramienen[n])==True:
    b.append(stramienen[n])
    c.append(gridcurves[n])
    e.append(re.findall('\d+',stramienen[n]))
```

Hope it helps. Good luck.